# hartl tutorial chapter 10 - unable to find ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling with one issue of the Hartl tutorial (where I've added my own custom needs, which is that a user belongs to a company, and the creation form is a company#new.) now everything is working, such as password reset etc. Except one thing which is the activation_token method.

Now I've tried to debug to get down to the exact line which is the problem and it is this one:

```
 @user.activation_token
```

when I try printing that out just generally for a logged in user it's blank. Now the accurate error I get is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"ex@ex.ex", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

the request parameters are as follows:

```
"company"=>{"users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"demo", "last_name"=>"demo", "email"=>"ex@ex.ex", "password"=>"demodemo"}}, "name"=>"demo"}
```

and the errors happen on:

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

my User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  ...

 class << self
    # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
    def digest(string)
      cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                    BCrypt::Engine.cost
      BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end

    # Returns a random token
    def new_token
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
 end

private

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
```

now it works in obtaining the ID when I have it in my test and do the following:

```
  def account_activation
    user = User.first
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    UserMailer.account_activation(user)
  end
```

and my companycontroller#create looks like this:

```
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
      user = @company.users.first
      user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "registerd and email sent"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'issues with creating user.'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

my company params:

```
  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, users_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password])
  end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  root    'welcome#index'
  get     'company/users' => 'companies#users'
  get     'login'         => 'sessions#new'
  post    'login'         => 'sessions#create'
  delete  'logout'        => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :companies
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

**note:** the user does successfully save, as does the company. I'm also able to obtain general user info, when I uncomment .activation_token I can see that I'm able to get the @user.first_name etc in the email from my console.

[image: on the picture you can see @user.activation_token is nil, but it finds the user object]

on the picture you can see that the @user.activation_token is nil, but it finds the @user object.

Comment: Please show your `company_params`. I assume you might be missing to permit `id` for user in there.

Comment: Okay I've updated to include my company params. However I do think the issue might be with activation_token

Comment: Where do you call your `create_activation_digest` method?

Comment: it's called on before_create  in the user model

Comment: Hm can you show your `routes.rb` too?

Comment: done - added my routes.rb !

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't your `activation_token` method, as that seems to be created and called - according to your screenshot.

The problem is you're populating the `edit_activations_path` with `@user.activation_token` (which won't include `id`), when that path requires `id`.

You should change it to:

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url @user %>
```

According to your routes (which I've improved below), and the Rails standard practice of passing *objects* to route actions means that you should pass the entire object, and let Rails determine the specifics.

Your error states that it's `id` that's not being passed - showing us that if you passed the `@user` object, instead of `@user.activation_token`, it will give Rails the ability to use it.

The only caveat here is that you may be calling `activation_token` and `email` in your `Activations` controller. If this is the case, you need to rework your routes to accept the token and email respectively (below):

---

There are a number of improvements you could make to your code:

--

Your routes can be made much more efficient:

```
 #config/routes.rb
  root    'welcome#index'

  resource  :company, only: [] do
     get :users, on: :collection
  end
  resources :companies, :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :sessions,            only: [:new, :create, :destroy], path_names: { new: "login", create: "login", destroy: "logout" }
```

Now, the important thing to note here is the `account_activations` resource is going to be the standard `Rails` resource... IE will expect `id` to formulate the route. Typical ID will be the primary_key of the object, you want to use the `activation_token`. To fix this, you should use the following:

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(id: @user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

This will still accept the params as `:id` (required) and `:email`, but will be populated with the data you need, allowing you to use:

```
#app/controllers/activations_controller.rb
class ActivationsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
     token = params[:id]
     email = params[:email]
   end
end
```

--

The model invokes `User` twice. You should call the following:

```
def create_activation_digest
  activation_token  = class.new_token
  activation_digest = class.digest(activation_token)
end
```